# zoom in jquery with holding the mouse

Tags: jquery, html, zooming

i am trying to write a code for zoom in and zoom out for all the body , now i found a code that do this but with a new click on the In and Out buttons .
what i need is to keep holding on the In button and to zoom automatically till i leave the mouse button, the same for the Out button...
here is my javascript and html code

```
  <script>
window.onload = function() {
var currFFZoom = 1;
var currIEZoom = 100;

$('#In').on('click',function(){
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1 && parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') + 8)) >= 3.6){//Firefox
        var step = 0.02;
        currFFZoom += step; 
        $('body').css('MozTransform','scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');
    } else {
        var step = 2;
        currIEZoom += step;
        $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%');
    }
});

$('#Out').on('click',function(){
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1 && parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') + 8)) >= 3.6){//Firefox
        var step = 0.02;
        currFFZoom -= step;                 
        $('body').css('MozTransform','scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');

    } else {
        var step = 2;
        currIEZoom -= step;
        $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%');
    }
});};
</script>
<img src="images/zoomin.png" style="cursor:pointer;" id="In" width="50" height="50" border="0" alt="zoom in" title="zoom in" /></br>
    <img src="images/zoomout.png" style="cursor:pointer;" id="Out" width="50" height="50" border="0" alt="zoom out" title="zoom out" />
```

can u edit my code or tell me some steps please to do that ?

Comment: the event you want is "mousedown" and "mouseup" not "click"

Answer (score 1):

this should be dooing it :

if i got you correct you want to zoom always, so i use document`s body as selector

```
 <script>
window.onload = function() {
    var currFFZoom = 1;
    var currIEZoom = 100;
    var k;
    $(document).on('mousedown','body',function(){
        k= setInterval(function(){
            if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1 && parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') + 8)) >= 3.6){//Firefox
                var step = 0.02;
                currFFZoom += step; 
                $('body').css('MozTransform','scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');
            } else {
                var step = 2;
                currIEZoom += step;
                $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%');
            }        
        },200);

    });

    $(document).on('mouseup','body',function(){
        clearInterval(k);
    });
};
</script>
```

the mouseup will be fired right when you release the mousebutton
but then you cant zoom out.

Comment: i cant success to put it into my code...can u do that please?

Comment: here u go, und mousedown tehres an interval that zzoom in until you release the mousebutton